# Spring MVC и Thymeleaf. Не могу корректно получить данные с html-страницы в контроллер

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Изучаю Java, Spring MVC и Thymeleaf. В html и Thymeleaf пока полный ноль. Не могу получить одновременно данные из двух форм в одном html-коде, точнее группа форм text и multiselect:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create user</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/user-create}" th:object="${users}" method="post">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <label>
        <select multiple size="2" th:name="roles" th:field="*{roles}">
            <option th:each="role : ${roles}" th:value="${role}" th:text="${role}"></option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Create User">
</form>

<p><a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Метод в контроллере, который ловит данные:

```java
@PostMapping("admin/user-create")
public ModelAndView createUser(User user, String[] roles) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    userService.saveUser(user);
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/admin/user-list");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Если у меня в параметрах метода что-то только одно, т. е. либо User user либо String[] roles, то отрабатывает на ура. А если оба сразу (как мне и надо), то вываливаюсь в HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request.

Comment: Считаю нужным написать, что решил проблему. Но проблема была совсем в другом, в моем файле html я не указал тег name, который передает значение на сервер. Я не знаю, как правильно оформить ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `@ModelAttribute` и `@RequestParam`

`@RequestParam` - ищет параметры в body и url

`@ModelAttribute` - заполняет поля объекта если их имена совпадают с полями формы

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create user</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/user-create}" method="post">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{password}" id="password" placeholder="Password">
    <label>
        <select multiple size="2" th:name="roles" th:field="*{roles}">
            <option th:each="role : ${roles}" th:value="${role}" th:text="${role}"></option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Create User">
</form>


<p><a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

```
@PostMapping("admin/user-create")
public ModelAndView createUser(@ModelAttribute User user,@RequestParam String[] roles) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    userService.saveUser(user);
    modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:/admin/user-list");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Если не получится, то добавьте уточнения:

```
public ModelAndView createUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,@RequestParam("roles") String[] roles)
```

и

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/user-create}" modelAttribute="user" method="post">
```

К `@RequestParam("roles")` можно добавить `required=false`, если это нужно